# Subsetting pandas dataframe based on two columnar values

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, subset

I am trying to subset a large dataframe (5000+ rows and 15 columns) based on unique values from two columns (both are dtype = object). I want to *exclude* rows of data that meet the following criteria:

A column called 'Record' equals "MO" **AND** a column called 'Year' equals "2017" or "2018".

Here is an example of the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1001,2002,3003,4004,5005,6006,7007,8008,9009], 'Record' : ['MO','MO','I','I','MO','I','MO','I','I'], 'Year':[2017,2019,2018,2020,2018,2018,2020,2019,2017]})
print(df)
    A     Record  Year
0  1001     MO  2017
1  2002     MO  2019
2  3003      I  2018
3  4004      I  2020
4  5005     MO  2018
5  6006      I  2018
6  7007     MO  2020
7  8008      I  2019
8  9009      I  2017
```

I would like any row with **both** "MO" and "2017", as well as **both** "MO" and "2018" taken out of the dataframe.

Example where the right rows (0 and 4 in dataframe above) are deleted:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2002,3003,4004,6006,7007,8008,9009], 'Record' : ['MO','I','I','I','MO','I','I'], 'Year':[2019,2018,2020,2018,2020,2019,2017]})
print(df)
     A   Record  Year
0  2002     MO  2019
1  3003      I  2018
2  4004      I  2020
3  6006      I  2018
4  7007     MO  2020
5  8008      I  2019
6  9009      I  2017
```

I have tried the following code, but it does not work (I tried at first for just one year):

```
df = df[(df['Record'] != "MO" & df['Year'] != "2017")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're just missing some parenthesis.

```
df = df[(df['Record'] != "MO") & (df['Year'] != "2017")]
```

**Edit:**
After some clarification:

```
df = df[~((df['Record']=='MO')&
          (df['Year']=='2017')|
          (df['Year']=='2018'))]
```

Comment: Thanks. I had done that as well, but it deleted all rows that included either "MO" or "2017". What I want to do is delete all rows that have BOTH "MO" and "2017", as well as BOTH "MO" and "2018", and keep everything else

Comment: Thanks. Your edit actually cut out one of the years entirely, but if they are split up in the following way sequentially, it works: 
```
df = df[~((df['Record']=='MO')&
          (df['Year']=='2017'))]   ;

df = df[~((df['Record']=='MO')&
          (df['Year']=='2018'))]
```